# C wire confusion

Tags: electrical, wiring, furnace, thermostat-c-wire

I have an old thermostat (20 + yrs old) that I want to replace with a Sensi smart thermostat. My furnace has a dull pink looking wire connected to the W terminal (also connected to the W on the old thermostat). The white wire is connect to the C terminal in the furnace and wrapped around the other wires connected to the old thermostat. I followed the instructions to install the new thermostat & used the white wire to the C terminal (since that was the one wrapped around the others). After the install & app setup I turned the power back on to the furnace, but I get no power to the thermostat leading me to believe that the white wire that's connected to the C terminal is not a power source for the thermostat??? I put the old one back on and everything worked as before.

Comment: Can you measure 24VAC from R to C at the thermostat?

Comment: Please [edit] to include brand/model of the furnace, as well as a clear pic of the wiring at the furnace and at the thermostat.

Comment: The C wire is usually blue (but not always). The white wire would be to turn on the heat. I've seen old thermostats not even use a c-wire and just tuck it away. There's also the possibility your white wire isn't even connected at the furnace (easily checked).  Your type of furnace/model would also help folks.